# Finding element by Xpath doesnt work properly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

# Inicializa el driver del navegador (en este caso, Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navega a la página web
driver.get('https://yopmail.com/es/email-generator')

# Localiza el elemento que quieres copiar (necesitarás el selector CSS correcto aquí)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                       "/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")))

mails = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")
mails = mails.text

print(mails)

driver.quit()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mback\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.idea\G-Mails.py", line 18, in <module>
    mails = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[This is the piece of text i want to copy(just the Email)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yih3s.png)

I want to copy the generated E-mail form the website an i cant, please help me

Comment: Instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")` it should be `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div")` because find_element_by_xpath is depreciated.

Comment: thank you so so much, i can continue my work now

Answer (score 0):

Above selenium version 4.x driver.find_element(By.xxx, "search_srting") must be used. Older versions used driver.find_element_by_xpath(...) syntax. It also alplies to find_elements(By.xxx, "search_string") calls to find multiple elements.

There are also other important differences introduced with the 4.x major version, a good summary and some guidace to port your code can be found here:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/